type of solutions of $-u^{\prime\prime}=\lambda e^{u}$ based on the value of the parameter $\lambda$. (Gelfand problem)
My question comes from the book
Stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations, Chapman & Hall/CRC Monographs and Surveys in Pure and Applied Mathematics 143. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4200-6654-8/hbk). xiv, 321 p. (2011) (MR2779463, Zbl 1228.35004) by Louis Dupaigne, pages 30-31.

Question: In the book, it defines $\lambda^{*}=\lambda^{*}(N)>0$ but dont give it any specific value and use it for the next statement: (Proposition 2.2.1 page 31 and Step 2 page 32). 
For some $\lambda^{*}>0$ there are exactly two solutions for $\lambda\in (0,\lambda^{*})$, one for $\lambda=\lambda^{*}$, and none $\lambda>\lambda^{*}$.\

How to prove it for the case $N=1$? The general problem is this
$$
    \begin{cases}
        -\Delta u=\lambda e^{u} & \text{in } B \\
            u=0         & \text{on } \partial B,
    \end{cases}
$$
where $\lambda>0$ is a parameter and $B$ is the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\geq 1$. 
For $N=1$, the problem is
\begin{equation}
    -u^{\prime\prime}=\lambda e^{u}, \quad u(-1)=u(1)=0.
\end{equation}

Searching documentations where it is explained or proved i have found this academic paper Summary of “Gelfand–type problems involving the 1–Laplacian operator”
Assume that the domain is an interval $(a, b)$, in this case the equation is
$$
-\left(\frac{u^{\prime}}{\left|u^{\prime}\right|}\right)^{\prime}=\lambda e^u
$$
In this setting, we prove the following result.
Theorem 3.1. Set $\lambda^*=\frac{2}{b-a}$.

If $\lambda>\lambda^*$, problem has no solution
If $0<\lambda \leq \lambda^*$, the minimal solution is the trivial solution
If $0<\lambda<\lambda^*$, there exist non trivial solutions
If $\lambda=\lambda^*$, there exists only trivial solution


But the theorem isn't proved in the text. In my case $b=-1$ and $a=1$, but I want to know where I can find a proof. Exist other forms to demostrate it or others theorems that i can use in this problem?
